# Complexity of height of a Tree

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, time-complexity

Consider the code :

```
int Tree::height(tree *node) {
    if (!node) return -1;

    return 1 + max(height(node->left), height(node->right));
}
```

What is the complexity of this method ? `O(n)` or `O(log(n))` ?

I think it's `O(n)` , since in the worst case we'd check all the nodes , doesn't ?

Can you give an example of a better implementation ?

Thanks

Comment: Trees only really shine if you balance them. Once balanced you know that the height/depth is log(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're checking all the nodes in all cases, not just the worst case. So yes, O(N).